# Share content via whatsapp in wp8 apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Just implemented sharing via SMS, Mail Twitter and Facebook with the from the WP8 SDK provided ShareStatusTask:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask(v=vs.105).aspx

Whatsapp does not seem to be supported here - do you guys know a trick to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically no, not yet, but something may come in the future using Uri Schemes.

For now, it seems that you can only run the WhatsApp app by doing this:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("whatsapp:"));
```

but on iPhone, you can use this form of Uri

```
whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!
```

so I expect the same functionality to appear in the near future in WhatsApp for Windows Phone. There's no reason why they wouldn't implement it.

In fact, maybe they already have, but I haven't found it publicly documented. See on Nokia Developer website for [other Uri Schemes](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can only make your App available as a means of photo sharing. (See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

There is no way to share to a particular third party App, unless it has "Extended the share picker" as seen at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can share text with whatsapp friends by using following URI scheme:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("whatsapp://send?text=Hello"));
```