# How to send message to whatsapp in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, whatsapp

I'm a beginner programmer in c#, and i wanna to start a huge project in c#.
I wanna send message to whatsapp.
Please give me a sample code or reference that can help me..
TNX

Comment: Sorry but Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems. _Give me codezzzz_ is not a good way to ask a question here. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: @SonerGönül is right. This sounds more like a case for Google.

Answer (score 2):

if think if you are trying to do it from desktop - then this is not possible if there is no such API provided from Whatsapp.

But if you are using Windows 8 or Windows Phone you could reffer to this:
[Share content via whatsapp in wp8 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146271/share-content-via-whatsapp-in-wp8-apps)

There is marked as an answer using a sharing contract.

As a suggestion you could create an application for WP and Desktop. The WP will be like a communicator between Whatsapp and Desktop. You will pass data to WP application and when recieved it will send data to Whatsapp

In details:

First you must check the provided link, if it is possible to send data via share contract. Share contracts have been presented in Windows 8 OS. So if the sharing contract works, and you still need to share data from Windows XP/Vista/7 i suggested you to writing an Windows phone or Windows 8, that will be installed on your tablet or mobile phone, and it will receive data by Http, Microsoft Notification service from your Windows XP/Vista/7 computer and send via sharing contract.

So the sharing will work like this:

If OS if Windows 8+

Windows 8+ -> Sharing contract -> Whatsapp

If lower:

Windows XP/Vista/7 -> Your additional app that will send message to mobile, tablet application -> Windows 8+ -> Sharing contract -> Whatsapp

**But only if provided link is correct, and sharing is possible to Whatsapp.**

But it seems that sharing is allowed, here is a link to Whatsapp FAQ:

http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: May you describe your suggest?